# Building flipper contract

Tags: smartcontracts, substrate, rust-ink

I am following this tutorial https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/building-your-contract but am getting the following error.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
➜  flipper cargo +nightly contract build
 [1/5] Building cargo project
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling flipper v0.1.0 (/tmp/cargo-contract_dLtaWE)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `__ink_ConstructorDispatchEnum: parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not satisfied
   --> /home/bill/flipper/lib.rs:5:1
    |
5   | #[ink::contract]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not implemented for `__ink_ConstructorDispatchEnum`
    | 
   ::: /home/bill/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_env-3.0.0-rc3/src/api.rs:465:8
    |
465 |     T: scale::Decode,
    |        ------------- required by this bound in `decode_input`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::codec::Decode` for `__ink_ConstructorDispatchEnum`
    = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `__ink_MessageDispatchEnum: parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not satisfied
   --> /home/bill/flipper/lib.rs:5:1
    |
5   | #[ink::contract]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not implemented for `__ink_MessageDispatchEnum`
    | 
   ::: /home/bill/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_env-3.0.0-rc3/src/api.rs:465:8
    |
465 |     T: scale::Decode,
    |        ------------- required by this bound in `decode_input`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::codec::Decode` for `__ink_MessageDispatchEnum`
    = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `flipper`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
ERROR: `"/home/bill/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "build" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Zbuild-std" "-Zbuild-std-features=panic_immediate_abort" "--no-default-features" "--release" "--target-dir=/home/bill/flipper/target"` failed with exit code: Some(101)
```

Comment: best would be to tag this `ink` `smart-contract` and join the https://matrix.to/#/#ink:matrix.parity.io chat to get support as well.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find this room on matrix.  I was only able to find #watercooler:matrix.parity.io

Comment: This looks like you might need to just update your Rust Compiler

Comment: I get the same error. I've already updated the compiler. @Bill have you solved the error ?

Comment: Solved by installing carg-contract v 0.10.0 instead 0.8.0